# Get numbers after a certain symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to select numbers that come after the `@` symbol but I'm struggling to make it work properly. Basically I have `@331` and I'm trying to select the `331`. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try: `/@(\d+)/` ?

Comment: Did you search for a solution on Stack Overflow or Google before asking? If so, please share your research so we can see what you're having issues with.

Comment: Show us what have you tried and we can help you out.

Comment: thanks bruh you the MVP

Comment: Hey @tonyh - I was working out something to show you before they closed that other question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174066/javascript-code-organization-with-game-prototype-with-methods (no other way to message you) I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using substr and indexOf functions of javascript

```html
    <html>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
        var afterDot = x.substr(x.indexOf('@')+1);
        alert(afterDot);
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <p id="demo">abc@332</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click it</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the split method and some cool Array methods:

```
"@123 someother @345".split("@").slice(1).map(str=>+str.split(" ")[0])
```

Will evaluate to

```
[123,345]
```

Comment: Ha. There is no way that is going to be useful to the OP. They are clearly just starting out.

Comment: @sheriffderek still the only real answer to the question... Feel free to either edit and explain, or add another answer with a proper explanation. I wont as the OP seems uninterested in working code...